# Use regressors in an STL forecast

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I'm using a STL decomposition to make forecasts in R (using the `forecast` package), but I'm not sure how to incorporate my regressors into the model.

I'm using the forecast function:

```
f = forecast(stl(my.data, s.window = 'periodic'), h = 12, method = 'arima')
```

The function above accepts the `xreg` parameter, but how do I specify the
model regressors and the forecast regressors?

Is there a function that does this or do I have to do it 'by hand'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do it by hand. The `forecast.stl()` function fits an ARIMA model to the de-seasonalized data, forecasts it, and then re-seasonalizes the forecasts. It is not set up to handle model regressors. If you include an `xreg` term it will use it when fitting the model, but then it will complain when forecasting because it won't know how to deal with future regressors.

`forecast.stl()` is a very simple function and could easily be modified to handle regressors. All you need is one extra argument for future regressors, and then change the line that calls `forecast()` with the fitted ARIMA model to include the future regressors.